# Error Al Publicar Página Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-server

Publique mi aplicación Angular pero me marca el siguiente error

[image: Ese error me marca]

Después investigando, me encontré que tenia que realizar el comando dotnet NombreApp.dll
y marca los siguientes errores:

[image: errores en cmd]

Llegue a un foro donde decían que una posible solucion actualizar `Install-Package Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design -Version 2.0.3` ya que tenia una versión mas arriba, al igual que el que marca los errores también lo deje en en la versión que indica pero sigue manteniendo el mismo error.

Comment: Win2008 es muy anciano!  Tiene https://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx instalado?

Comment: ¿Tienes instalado el Runtime de net core en el server?

Comment: Así es, Si tengo instalado pero aun así sigue marcando el error